# What is the reason that admin panel of wordpress has been broken in such a way?

Tags: javascript, php, html, wordpress

What is the reason that admin panel of wordpress has been broken in such a way?
[image]

Comment: What is the reason you haven't read [how-to-ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: What is the reason you haven't tried to fix yourself ?

Comment: Try to check word press version, plugin version , because if any of function gets deprecate it throw an error in admin.

Answer (score 1):

Deactivate recently install plugins and check. otherwise dDeacitvate each plugin one by one and check.

Comment: @Narek this is how you debug something like that. If you don't like the answers, then you should have never asked the question in the first place :-)

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand your question properly but I think the style has broken. One of your Plugin stylesheets might have broken the admin site layout. Deacitvate each plugin one by one and check which plugin causing this issue.

Comment: what you mean by no ?

Answer (score -1):

Download source code of wordpress from https://wordpress.org/download/, drop database and do installation again. It will work.